# Nesting controls inside NSTableView rows

Tags: cocoa

Is there a way to nest complex views - in particular an NSTokenView - inside *each row* of an NSTableView or NSOutlineView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is yes.

Cocoa's user interface elements are implemented as a combination of two parts: a control (a complete subclass of NSView) and a cell (which handles the actual drawing and keyboard/mouse interaction). See [Control and Cell Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/ControlCell.html) for all of the dirty details.

In `NSTableView` and `NSOutlineView`, you can specify the cell class that gets used for each `NSTableColumn` (or even for each individual element, if you want to go that far). You can use [`NSButtonCell`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [`NSTextFieldCell`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextFieldCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and even [`NSTokenFieldCell`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenFieldCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTokenFieldCell).

The documentation on [`setDataCell:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableColumn_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableColumn/setDataCell:) has more of the details.